# Optimize SELECT query with ORDER BY, OFFSET and LIMIT of postgresql

Tags: postgresql

This is my table schema

```
Column       |          Type          |                      Modifiers                      
-------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
id           | integer                | not null default nextval('message_id_seq'::regclass)
date_created | bigint                 |
content      | text                   |
user_name    | character varying(128) |
user_id      | character varying(128) |
user_type    | character varying(8)   |
user_ip      | character varying(128) |
user_avatar  | character varying(128) |
chatbox_id   | integer                | not null
Indexes:
    "message_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "idx_message_chatbox_id" btree (chatbox_id)
    "indx_date_created" btree (date_created)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "message_chatbox_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (chatbox_id) REFERENCES chatboxes(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This is the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM message 
WHERE chatbox_id=$1 
ORDER BY date_created 
OFFSET 0 
LIMIT 20;
```

($1 will be replaced by the actual ID)

It runs pretty well, but when it reaches 3.7 millions records, all SELECT queries start consuming a lot of CPU and RAM and then the whole system goes down. I have to temporarily backup all the current messages and truncate that table. I am not sure what is going on because everything is ok when I have about 2 millions records

I am using Postresql Server 9.1.5 with default options.

---

Update the output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..6.50 rows=20 width=99) (actual time=0.107..0.295 rows=20 loops=1)
->  Index Scan Backward using indx_date_created on message  (cost=0.00..3458.77 rows=10646 width=99) (actual time=0.105..0.287 rows=20 loops=1)
Filter: (chatbox_id = 25065)
Total runtime: 0.376 ms
(4 rows)
```

---

Update server specification

```
Intel Xeon 5620 8x2.40GHz+HT
12GB DDR3 1333 ECC
SSD Intel X25-E Extreme 64GB
```

---

**Final solution**

Finally I can go above 3 million messages, I have to optimize the postgresql configuration as  wildplasser suggested and also make a new index as A.H. suggested

Comment: Can you add `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the query?

Comment: `I am using Postresql Server 9.1.5 with default options.` You could start by setting estimated_cache_size to 3/4 of your available RAM, and setting work_mem to ~10M. And *maybe* set random_page_cost to 1.5. and run `VACUUM ANALYZE` on all relevant tables.

Comment: Have you run an `ANALYZE` on the table recently?

Comment: I have updated the ouput of EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Comment: @laoshanlung: The `EXPLAIN` output seems to be OK. So I guess it is the good case, not the bad case. Of course the bad case is the interesting thing.

Comment: @laoshanlung BTW: linking to pastbin is not recommended style. Everyhting related to the question should be visible in the question. If someone in the future researches a similar problem the pastbin stuff might be gone.

Comment: @laoshanlung Adding `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, not only `EXPLAIN` could be better. Details and differences here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html

Comment: @A.H. I tend to view http://explain.depesz.com/ as an exception to that, just because query plans there are so much nicer to work with. That said unless it's a huge plan I usually paste it inline *and* add a link.

Comment: I have updated my table schema and EXPLAIN ANALYZE ouput

Comment: @laoshanlung Using postgresql with default options and big amoutn of data is a bad idea. Please read also answers from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407555/postgresql-query-taking-too-long maybe LIMIT is breaking your execution plans.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to give PostgreSQL a better index for that query. I propose something like this:

```
create index invent_suitable_name on message(chatbox_id, date_created);
```

or

```
 create index invent_suitable_name on message(chatbox_id, date_created desc);
```

Comment: You do not need specify `desc` for index fields for postgres. Postgres can scan indexes in both directions.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko While true, creating the index sorted in the correct direction will make the index scan considerably faster. Backward index scans are quite a bit slower.

Comment: I posted my table schema, I have already had index for chatbox_id and date_created

Comment: @CraigRinger Thank you, Didn't know about that (as always not everything is in the manual).

Comment: @laoshanlung: Currently you have *two* indizes each one containing *one* field. My proposal creates *one* index covering *both* fields. From a performance view this is **very** different.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding an index for `chatbox_id, date_created`. For this particular query it will give you  maximum performance.

For the case, when postgres "start consuming a lot of CPU and RAM" try to get more details. It could be a bug (with default configuration postgres normally doesn't consume much RAM).

UPD My guess for the reason of bad performance:

At some point in time the table becomes to big for full scan to collect accurate statistics. After another `ANALYZE` Postgresql got bad statistics for the table. As a result - got bad plan that consisted of:

1. Index scan on `chatbox_id`;
2. Ordering of returned records to get top 20.

Because of default configs and lots of records, returned on step 1, postgres was forced to do sorting in files on disk. As a result - bad performance.

UPD2 `EXPALIN ANALYZE` shows `0.376 ms` time and a good plan. Can you give details about a case with bad performance?

Comment: I updated my server specification, I think it is powerful enough for handling 3 millions records, isn't it?

Comment: @laoshanlung With default configurations postgresql will use like 10% of server power. + a bad query plan can slow down any server.